# Configure UTF-8 Encoding in JBOSS 6.1 EAP

Tags: encoding, jboss, character-encoding, jboss6.x

I'm using JBoss 6.1 EAP and I'm having some problems with the encoding.
I need to set the enconding to UTF-8.
I search and i'm found some solutions but no one works, anything have some suggets?

I try this but doesn't work:

```
<system-properties>
<property name="org.apache.catalina.connector.URI_ENCODING" value="UTF-8"/>
<property name="org.apache.catalina.connector.USE_BODY_ENCODING_FOR_QUERY_STRING" value="true"/>
```

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Property `org.apache.catalina.connector.URI_ENCODING` relates to URI Encoding not the content of the request/response for that you'll need to check:

web.xml

```
 <jsp-config>
     <jsp-property-group>
         <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
         <page-encoding>UTF-8</page-encoding>
     </jsp-property-group>
 </jsp-config>
```

Enforce encoding with filters:

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    response.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");
    request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```

JSP directives "pageEncoding" or html meta tags

```
<%@ page pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>

<meta charset="UTF-8"/>
```

and finally System Property

```
file.encoding=UTF-8
```